# Android MySQLLite select query not working, does not fetch results from code

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

I am developing an Android application and have a following query:

```
result = myDataBase.query(HD_TABLENAME, new String[]{HD_KEYDATE, HD_KEYFESTID},
         "YEAR = "+ year +" AND MONTH = " + month, null, null, null, HD_KEYDATE);
```

I have written a custom DataBaseHelper which calls this query.

The above results into the following query:

```
SELECT DATE, FESTIVALID FROM HOLIDAYDATES WHERE YEAR = 2010 AND MONTH = 1 ORDER BY DATE
```

when i execute the same query from SQLLite admin on the same file, it returns the required rows.

There is no exception, how can i get the above to work.
The database exists and It works for a previous query.
Is there any property of the result object which I can check to see what is the exact error?

NOT SURE IF THIS WILL HELP:
A logcat message that I get after the execution  of the query :

> 04-19 10:39:54.803: DEBUG/SntpClient(71): request time failed:    java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

CLARIFICATION:
One of the properties has this:
result.mStackTrace has the value = android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Now, I guess first I have to close and open some cursor which I foolishly left open, but now trying to find it, if you can suggest anything, please do.

ADDITIONAL QUESTION, is there any way to see the open connections to the database?

Comment: where are you getting the error? you do not say. Have you checked logcat? You can put a `Try {} catch(Exception e) { Log.d("blah", e.getMessage())}` around your db query call

Comment: There is no error, that is the problem it compiles and runs fine, but gives zero rows in the result, while the same query works like a charm in the SQLLite admin .. :/

Comment: hmm thats a wierd one. I know you say there is no error but just to be sure did you try enclosing the call in try{} catch() {} ?

Comment: It is surrounded by try{}catch{} and earlier when i missed the openDatabase(), it threw an exception and i resolved it, but this one .... definitely weird ... :P

Comment: i noticed your edit of the "Address family not supported by protocol" error. That definitely sounds suspicious. I tried googling and is a socket exception but couldn't see any thing helpful

Comment: Can any android expert try to solve the issue if they are remotely connected to my workstation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You used.

dataBase = this.openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

Comment: Oh yes, the Database connection is open, other queries are working fine!
The issue is that I get no rows from this query ...Is there any property of the returned cursor which can tell me why?? :/

Comment: There was a cursor open, but this is the closes to the answer.